# Axios request on frontend doesnt load the data I need from MongoDB database on backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

> Calling backend to load posts from mongoDB. works in postman. Shows 
>   custom error on frontend. Don't understand why it wont work. Using 
>   Redux to load user info for axios call

```
  componentDidMount() {
     if (!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
     this.props.history.push('/');
  }

axios
  .get('http://localhost:5000/auth/loadUserPosts', {
    name: this.props.auth.user.name
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}


 router.get('/loadUserPosts', (req, res) => {
 const author = req.body.name;

Post.find({ author: author })
.then(posts => {
  // If the users posts are less than or equal to zero. the 'error' message will appear
  if (posts.length <= 0) {
      res({
      message: 'There is no posts for this user. Or the user does not exist'
    });
  } else {
    res(posts);
  }
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: *What* custom error?

Comment: Custom error was not the right choice of word. I was referring to the response that says there is no posts. Sorry about that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const author = req.body.name;
```

Change above to this

```
const author = req.query.name;
```

In postman you might be getting in body, but with axios you will get in `req.params`